# Not returning back to selenium after successful execution of autoit

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

I am trying to download and  save a document to my local machine from the application on click of an export button.
On click of export button continue to this website(not recommended) error will open in another window.On click of this window save pop up of IE11 comes up.
Trying to use autoit to select save option from the pop up that comes up in IE11 while downloading.This successfully downloads the file but the control is not returning to the selenium script and the selenium script is not terminated.After download i have written java code to check if the file exists in a particular path.The script doesnot go to this part of the code.Please help

Below is my auto it code
WinWaitActive("Internet Explorer","",40)

```
  Send("{TAB}")--->by default selection is in "Open".So tabbing into "Save"
  Send("{ENTER}")
```

In selenium webdriver Iam calling auto it like
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec((path of the file)+"Download_IE.exe");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i tried to do download manually ,after clicking on save the pop up closes automatically.but while running the script after clicking on save the window was not closed by itself.When i closed the window through script it started working.

WinClose("window title")

The script was hanging at that point.
Issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Autoit is not working for me while downloading from IE, I use awt robot class, to download a file from IE please refer below

```
public static void clickAndSaveFileIE(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException{
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // get the focus on the element..don't use click since it stalls the
        // driver
        element.sendKeys("");
        // simulate pressing enter
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        // wait for the modal dialog to open
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // press s key to save
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);


        //press enter to save the file with default name and in default location

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //press key  F6
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F6);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F6);
        //press key Tab
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

 } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```